Service Principal Updated by Microsoft Certificate?
Curious and so far unexplainable question.
Exchange admin center decided to flip for login enabled to disabled all on its own today. On digging into the unified audit log I saw the following:
Operation
Update service principal.

ModifiedProperties
[
    {
        "Name": "AccountEnabled",
        "NewValue": "[\r\n  false\r\n]",
        "OldValue": "[\r\n  true\r\n]"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Included Updated Properties",
        "NewValue": "AccountEnabled",
        "OldValue": ""
    },
    {
        "Name": "TargetId.ServicePrincipalNames",
        "NewValue": "497effe9-df71-4043-a8bb-14cf78c4b63b",
        "OldValue": ""
    }
]

Actor
[
    {
        "ID": "Microsoft Online Services",
        "Type": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": "Certificate",
        "Type": 2
    },
    {
        "ID": "Other",
        "Type": 2
    }
]

The Exchange Admin Center application (497effe9-df71-4043-a8bb-14cf78c4b63b) is standard and matches the application ID here.
Any idea what or why caused this event to occur?
It is the first time I see this happening.
The only other thing I have to add is that the ActorContextID matches my OrganizationId for the record.
